# mpirun with ssh and X11

Tags: ubuntu, x11, mpi

At present we're trying to write a program which uses mpirun to launch multiple X11 clients. If the programs are text-only, then using the following command, we can run proceses on a list of computers:

```
mpirun -np 4 --hostfile hostlist date
```

Here hostlist is a file of mpi-configured computers. The computers are set up to authenticate automatically using public keys. We can also run X11 programs on the local computer only, for instance:

```
mpirun -np 4 xclock
```

shows four xclocks as expected. However, if we try to run X11 programs using a hostfile:

```
mpirun -np 4 --hostfile hostlist xclock
```

then two xclocks launch but the remote computer reports:

```
Error: can't open display:
```

However, we have configured *.ssh/config* with

```
ForwardX11 Yes
```

And we can verify that the following command sequence works:

```
ssh 10.0.0.2
# connect to mpi cluster node
xclock
# xclock appears on screen
```

Furthermore, if we set a DISPLAY variable with mpirun's -x as follows:

```
mpirun -np 4 --hostfile hostlist -x DISPLAY=10.0.0.1:0.0 xclock
```

Then we get another error:

```
Error: can't open display: 10.0.0.1:0.0
```

We tried to disable any access control with:

```
xhost +
```

To summarize, we'd like some help with mpirun and X11 Forwarding. We're running on Ubuntu 12.10 and openmpi 1.4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following command seems to work well

```
mpirun -d -np 4 -hostfile hostlist -mca pls_rsh_agent "ssh -X -n" xclock
```

Comment: So the combination of enabling debugging and setting the pls_rsh_agent variable are required.